# Unique Sets from collection of Sets

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, set

I do have `int` pairs, i.e; (int ,int)

> 1) Given k such pairs, check if they are unique. i.e; size of the Set formed using k pairs is k ?
>   2) if the given k records are unique then store them in sorted order ( by x and resolve conflict by y)
>   3) Given n such sets of size k, create a set of sets.

Example of requirement 1 and 2
if k = 3

> (100, 100)  (110, 300) (120, 200) is a valid set and in sorted order.
>   (100, 100)  (300, 200) (200, 300) is a valid set but not in sorted order.
>   (100, 100)  (100, 200) (100, 200) is in valid set

Example of requirement 3
input:

> (100, 100)  (200, 300) (300, 200)
>   (100, 100)  (200, 300) (300, 200)
>   (100, 100)  (201, 300) (300, 200)

output:

> (100, 100)  (200, 300) (300, 200)
>   (100, 100)  (201, 300) (300, 200)

This is the closest analogy to the real problem i am facing. I need to get this done in Java and i have never worked in java. I am a intermediate c++ programmer.

I could solve 1 and 2 via some ugly coding and sorting.
However i am not able to get 3.  Below is what i could get so far for 3. The class pair implements comparable

(poc code)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class set {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        HashSet<Pair> s1 = new HashSet();
        s1.add(new Pair(10,10));
        s1.add(new Pair(10,10));

        HashSet<Pair> s2 = new HashSet();
        s2.add(new Pair(10,10));
        s2.add(new Pair(10,10));

        HashSet<HashSet<Pair>> s12 = new HashSet();
        s12.add(s1);s12.add(s2);
        for ( HashSet<Pair> hs : s12) {
            for (Pair p :  hs) {
                System.out.println(""+ p.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes and No.
I started exploring computational geometry algorithms via homework problem. Before moving the line sweep and other algorithms i wanted to try something on my own 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection

Comment: What's exactly wrong with your HashSet of HashSet code? It looks OK, give or take a few unchecked operations.

Comment: First  
HashSet<Pair> Is not recognizing duplicates.     
If i had to check (10,10)(10,10) makes a set pairs of size 2 with unique pairs, then the code written above is not working. Ideally s1 should have had only (10,10) after inserting the pair 2 times.  
I need to know how i can make it a sorted set with custom compare()/equal  

Similar is the issue with HashSet<HashSet<pair>> which should be collection of unique HashSet<pair>  

The output of the above code should be     
(10, 10) ( ignoring k must be 2)     

However it is printing   
(10, 10)  
(10, 10)  
(10, 10)  
(10, 10)

Comment: How is Pair defined? Specifically, does it correctly implement `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: pair implements comparable. I am yet to figure out how to make it implement both/all. i.e; comparable,equals, hashCode. (Basically implementing multiple interfaces. In C++ i would do multiple inheritance , not sure about java syntax)  
My main concerns would be, Is the approach i'm taking efficient?  
Are there better collections for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't override `equals` and/or `hashCode` methods in Pair class.

For example if your `Pair` class has the following structure :

```
protected K value1;
protected V value2;
```

You should implement `equals` and `hashCode` as(example) :

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Pair))
        return false;
    Pair that = (Pair)obj;
    boolean result = true;
    if (this.getValue1() != null)
        result = this.getValue1().equals(that.getValue1());
    else if (that.getValue1() != null)
        result = that.getValue1().equals(this.getValue1());

    if (this.getValue2() != null)
        result = result && this.getValue2().equals(that.getValue2());
    else if (that.getValue2() != null)
        result = result && that.getValue2().equals(this.getValue2());

    return result;
} 


public int hashCode() {
    int result = value1 != null ? value1.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (value2 != null ? value2.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is what i was missing.  But overall, are there better approaches to deal with problem ?

Comment: I think the better way is to use TreeSet rather than HashSet, since you want to store your pair objects in sorted order. In any case you have to implement equals and hashCode..